# Fixing GUI output, Adding 2 JPanel to single JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

When the user enter a character in a text field it should draws a rectangle in the orange part as shown ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSoMC.png.

[image]

when the character is entered the text field the rectangle is drawn but the output is not what expected ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jGVr.png.

[image]

Is it possible to fix this problem??

Comment: Without code, it's hard to say what you could be doing wrong.

Comment: ....................never mind.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm only assuming based on available evidence :P

Comment: ......... and 1+ to your answer @MadProgrammer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1. Very impressive !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding `paint` or `paintComponent` of a component/container without calling `super.paint` or `super.paintComponent` first

`Graphics` is a shared resource, every component which is painted in a single paint cycle will be given the same `Graphics` context, so what was previously painted to it will still be there. One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context, typically by filling it with the components background color.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Comment: Pro!.. I voted up but not enough reputation. Thank you